# Python, How do I use a string in a while loop and then an if statement?

Tags: python, string, variables, int

I cannot figure out why this won't work, I have gone as far as to apply integer variables, I would prefer to keep it purely to strings. I'm new, what am I doing wrong?

```
x = int(2)
y = int(1)
while userinput != (1,2):
userinput = input("Do you wish to continue, to start from scratch?")
if input == 1:
    print("y")
if input == 2:
    print ("n")
else:
    print("Try y or n, they mean yes or no respectively.")
```

Comment: It's not properly indented. Maybe that's what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Verify userinput in the if's, after converting it to integer. input() returns a string.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: Simply keeps continuing the while loop, it should equal 1 or 2 after an x or y input has been reached?

Comment: You donot need to write int(2)..it is already an integer..

Comment: I thought so, but I was trying anything to get it to work.

Comment: The first problem is that your indentation is invalid. The next problem is that you try to check `userinput` in the `while` condition before you ever assign to it. Next, no string the user enters will ever be equal to the tuple `(1, 2)`. `int(userinput)` might be `in` that tuple, however. Likewise, no string will ever be equal to the number `1` or `2`, but `int(userinput)` might. Finally, that "Try y or n…" message is pretty misleading when you're requiring them to type `1` or `2` instead of `y` or `n`.

Comment: `if input == 1` but you assign your input to a var named `userinput`. I really wonder how this can run in an infinite loop

Comment: Just ignore the indentation, that was just what happened when I posted this.

Comment: It says while userinput != (1,2):

Comment: (1,2) is a tuple, better make it  while userinput not in (1,2):

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to check directly on the "y" and "n" characters, note that, among the other things, in your code you are checking the wrong input, you should check the variable **userinput** that you assign in the loop with the user input.

Here is a working example, note that i convert to lowercase in order to accept both "y\n" and "Y\N" with a single if statement.

```
userinput = ""
while (userinput !="y" and userinput !="n"):
  userinput = input("Do you wish to continue, to start from scratch?").lower()

  if userinput == "y":
    print("y")
  elif userinput == "n":
    print ("n")
  else:
    print("Try y or n, they mean yes or no respectively.")
```

EDIT: if statement fixed as suggested by @Kumar

Comment: I think for the logic OP wants to implement, the code should have all the conditions in the same `if-elif-else` statement. Otherwise, for `userinput=="y"` also, it will print the message.